# Javascript classlist not working as expected

Tags: javascript, html, toggle

I simply want to call classList on an element a second time.  The first half of the code should affect all elements with the class 'btn'.  The second half should only affect all elements with the 'data-test' attribute.

How come the elements with the 'data-test' attribute are not receiving the treatment from having the '.btn' class?  They should get both 'selected' and 'bar' classes toggled to them, but are only getting the 'bar' class toggled to them (JSFiddle provided).

HTML

```
<button class="btn">Button</button>
<button class="btn">Button</button>

<button class="btn" data-test="button">Button</button>
<button class="btn" data-test="button">Button</button>
```

JS

```
// First half

var btn = document.querySelectorAll('.btn');

for (var i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
    btn[i].onclick = function() {
        this.classList.toggle('selected');
    }
}


// Second half

var items = document.querySelectorAll('[data-test]');

for (var f = 0; f < items.length; f++) {
    items[f].onclick = function() {
        this.classList.toggle('bar');
    }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jstn/uxdb8836/

Help is super appreciated thank you!

Comment: Aren't you overriding onclick function? In jQuery you can add multiple onclick handlers, but I'm not sure if that's possible in pure Javascript.

Comment: @Keammoort You are correct about overriding - I was not aware of this.  However, you must understand that jQuery is written in Javascript.  So it uses pure Javascript to do everything it does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because you're overwriting the handler. An element can have only one handler assigned to a `onclick` property.

Instead, use `.addEventListener()` to bind the handler.

```js
var btn = document.querySelectorAll('.btn');

for (var i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
  btn[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle('selected');
  }, false);
}

var items = document.querySelectorAll('[data-test]');

for (var f = 0; f < items.length; f++) {
  items[f].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle('bar');
  }, false);
}
```

```css
.selected {
  background-color: orange;
  }
```

```html
<button class="btn">Button</button>
<button class="btn">Button</button>

<button class="btn" data-test="button">Button</button>
<button class="btn" data-test="button">Button</button>
```

---

Side note, you can reuse those functions for memory efficiency.

```
function btnHandler() {
    this.classList.toggle('selected');
}
function testHandler() {
    this.classList.toggle('bar');
}

var btn = document.querySelectorAll('.btn');

for (var i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
    btn[i].addEventListener("click", btnHandler, false);
}

var items = document.querySelectorAll('[data-test]');

for (var f = 0; f < items.length; f++) {
    items[f].addEventListener("click", testHandler, false);
}
```

Comment: Great answer and makes much more sense since you revised, thank you.  Could you tell me what is the best way to keep this working in IE8?  Would it be to just include a shim or work around it with a conditional statement?

Comment: @JustinBreen: Yeah, sorry. I glossed over it too fast at first. And yes, there are shims available to modernize a whole bunch of IE8 stuff, like `.addEventListener()`. You can conditionally load them with IE conditional comments.

Comment: No problem it's a perfect answer.  I'm trying to build a mini library that I can include on all my projects - so perhaps I could include the shim as part of the library (already including classless shim too) and maybe in a couple years just delete it.  Do you think that would still be more efficient than using jQuery?

Comment: @JustinBreen: I personally like the idea of not having to load large libraries. I use my own micro library as well. You could certainly include the shim but it would be unfortunate to have all your clients download that code when it's only needed for IE8. Native code will always be faster than jQuery but any shim will have its own overhead. That's unavoidable. Shouldn't matter too much though. Because a shim will likely extend the host `.prototype`, it should be working directly with elements instead of allocating a wrapper, so it should be plenty fast.

Comment: Make sense to me thanks for the explanation.  Perhaps I may not need to include IE8 support - I just like the idea of 'bulletproof' minimal code.  I think as of now I should still include the classlist shim for IE9 users.  If IE8 is just about finally dying now, there's got to be plenty of IE9 users out there.

Comment: Sounds like a plan. Best of luck!

Comment: @squint are there any handler amount limitations?

Comment: @MedetTleukabiluly: I'm not aware of any such limitation in the spec. Very doubtful that they would limit the number of handlers per event.

Comment: @squint removed my answer, why you use community wiki? it doesn't give rep thought

Comment: @MedetTleukabiluly: I just don't care about the rep, and would rather have my answers open to additions and improvements by others.

Comment: @squint well, it's kinda common, i have low rep - i do care, you have 29k - u dont care. World is logical

Comment: @MedetTleukabiluly: I answered enough questions to get my rep over 20k, so that I could have the full set of basic site tools. I don't impose this as an expectation on others. It's just how I prefer it.

Comment: @MedetTleukabiluly: By the way, I made [a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6cLn2agz/1/) to show the issue you had. You can create a new scope in the block by using an IIFE or some other function, though you should probably still drop the `.bind()` in favor of a simple `.call()`.

Comment: @squint forgot about this, nice lesson, thanks, forked it http://jsfiddle.net/g7nfswhe/

Comment: @MedetTleukabiluly: Yep, looks perfect.